# Get value from another workbook using vba where values match?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following workbook:

Master workbook

```
Column E         Column G        Column J        Column V
                                                 Expecting
12/12/2016       111             555       
12/12/2015       222             444
12/12/2014       333             666
```

I also have a workbook called slave:

Slave workbook

```
Column C     Column D        Column E       Column F         Column G
111          555             12/12/2016                      400
222          444                            12/12/2015       500
333          666             12/12/2014                      600
```

If the values in each column in master match with those in the slave  workbook, i want to copy the value from column G from slave, over to Column v in my master.

At the moment my code works if i check the following criteria:

```
Master                    Slave    
Column G    MATCHES       Column C 

Column J    MATCHES       Column D
```

However, if i want to check the date in column E on my master workbook matches column E on the slave workbook my code stops working.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oCell As Range, oCell2 As Range, oCell3 As Range, oCell4 As Range, targetCell As Range
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    If Target.Column = 22 And ActiveCell.Value = "Expecting" Then

        If Not GetWb("Order Checker", ws2) Then Exit Sub

        lastRow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With ws2
            For Each targetCell In Range("J6:J" & lastRow)
                Set oCell = .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=targetCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                Set oCell2 = .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=targetCell.Offset(0, -3).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                Set oCell3 = .Range("F1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=targetCell.Offset(0, -5).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

                MsgBox oCell3
                If Not oCell Is Nothing And Not oCell2 Is Nothing And Not oCell3 Is Nothing Then


                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    targetCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 3)

                    Application.EnableEvents = True

                End If



            Next
        End With


        End If


End Sub

Function GetWb(wbNameLike As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "*" & wbNameLike & "*" Then '<-- check if workbook name contains "Depot Memo"
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(2)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetWb = Not ws Is Nothing
End Function
```

The problem is to do with this:

```
Set oCell3 = .Range("E1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=targetCell.Offset(0, -5).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

FOr some reason, oCell3 says it = Nothing.

So when i'm testing if oCell3 is not nothing like so:

```
If Not oCell3 Is Nothing Then
```

This is causing my code to not produce a result.

Can someone please show me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Didn't you already post this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue could be that in `ws2` dates are actually a `String` value while the searched date is a *real* `Date`.

in this case you could use:

```
Set oCell3 = .Range("F1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=CStr(targetCell.Offset(0, -5)), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```